# check if rows are already present in pyspark dataset

Tags: python, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, pyspark-schema

The schema of my output and input dataset is the same. Upon running this script, I want to first check create a new dataset using the filter_data function and save the results in a dataframe variable called "alerts". Now, I want to check if there are any rows in this "alerts" dataframe that are not already present in my existing output.

If there are no new rows, I want to return the existing output as it is (without any changes) so that the output dataset is not updated and the health checks on the output dataset are not triggered.

However, if the "alerts" dataset has new data that's not already present in the Output dataset, then i want to return "alerts" dataset.

```
from transforms.api import configure, transform_df, Input, Output
from numpy import mean, std
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@configure(profile=[
    "DRIVER_MEMORY_MEDIUM"
    ])
@incremental(snapshot_inputs=['violations'])
@transform_df(
    Output("/Spring/Snowplow/data/derived/output_dataset"),
    violations=Input("xxx"),
)
def compute(violations, output):

    alerts = filter_data(violations, output)
    alerts_df = alerts.subtract(output)
    
    if alerts_df.count() > 0:
        return alerts
    else:
        return output



def filter_data(violations, output):

    todays_date = F.current_date()
    violations = violations.filter(F.col("failure_date") == todays_date)

    columns_to_keep = [
        "id",
        "value_1",
        "value_2",
        "date",
        "timestamp",
    ]
    return violations.select(*columns_to_keep)
```

This is what I am trying but currently I seem to be getting an error:

```
TypeError: compute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two separate issues in your code that may be causing problems.

**First**, you can use either of the following:

```
@transform_df(
    Output("/Spring/Snowplow/data/derived/output_dataset"),
    violations=Input("xxx"),
)
```

or

```
@transform(
    output=Output("/Spring/Snowplow/data/derived/output_dataset"),
    violations=Input("xxx"),
)
```

But you can't use what you currently have, which is:

```
@transform_df(
    output=Output("/Spring/Snowplow/data/derived/output_dataset"),
    violations=Input("xxx"),
)
```

The difference has to do with how the [`transform` API](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/transforms-python-api/index.html#transform) takes different arguments than the [`transform_df` API](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/transforms-python-api/index.html#transform_df).

I would recommend using `transform` just like how it's used in [this example in the docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/incremental-examples/index.html#merge-and-replace). What you call "output" in your example is called "processed" in that example. It accesses the data in the previous transaction of the output dataset and uses it in the current transaction.

**Second**, in order to accomplish what you're trying to do here, you should leverage the ability to [abort transactions](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/abort-transactions/index.html#abort-transactions). [This example in the docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/abort-transactions/index.html#example-notional-custom-condition) seems pretty similar to what you're trying to accomplish. This will "allow a job to successfully complete if the output dataset is unchanged (where no new data is written to the dataset)."

**Lastly**, I think there's an error in your `filter_data` function in that it doesn't require an `output` argument under any scenario. And the code you shared is passing in `schema_violations` when that isn't defined anywhere and should probably be just `violations` based on what I'm seeing in your code snippet.

Comment: If I go with the first option, how do I use the "output" in my functions then? when there's no variable to use within a function

Comment: the docs example is with transform and not transform_df

Comment: Given the code you shared, I don't see a need to use `output` in any of your functions. However, you may do that if you'd like by using the `transform` decorator. You can substitute the `transform` decorator as long as you use `output=Output(...`. That is, for this situation you can use whichever one you'd prefer.

Comment: Given that I use the transform_df, not transform, how can I still subtract or filter data (as shown in the docs example). What do I use as the second variable then?

Comment: added an edited snippet, which still gives the same error

Comment: Makes sense. The reason you're still getting the error is that you're using "output" in your function "compute", but no such thing is getting passed into the "compute" function because there's not "output" variable in the "transform_df" decorator. I updated my answer with a recommendation + a link to an example in the docs that should help clarify things. Basically, use the "transform" decorator with "output" specified; and refer to the linked doc to access the previous transaction of the output dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In `@transform_df` you don't need to pass the output explicitly and you also don't need to explicitly call `.dataframe()` on your Inputs. These are only needed if you are using `@transform`

I would recommend this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCKxfnP2ZNU

Comment: Do you mean I can remove the "output" from output=Output and still use "output" as the parameter of the compute function?

Comment: With the current code, I still get the same error